# Target slides by z-index and assign class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

here is what I am trying to achieve. On this page http://livinginspace.staging.wpengine.com/ there are four sharing buttons. First three work perfectly fine, but the houzz works only for one image. What I am trying to achieve is to dynamicly change the button's href attribute depending on the current slide, so when you press it you are sharing the slide that was on the screen when you pressed the houzz button.
As I noticed, all you need to change inside the href of the button is the image url. Also, the only thing that changes (at least that I've noticed) is the z-index of the li element inside the slider div.
Here are my steps:
//first I am targeting the li with z-index 20

```
var currLi = $('li').filter(function() {
return $(this).css('z-index') == 20;
});
```

//then i target the url of the image inside that li

```
var imgUrl = $(currLi + '>div.slotholder>img').attr('src');
```

//finally I put the url into the houzz button

```
$('a.sb_network_button.houzz').attr("href", "http://www.houzz.com/imageClipperUpload?link=http%3A%2F%2Flivinginspace.staging.wpengine.com%2F&amp;source=button&amp;hzid=4036&amp;imageUrl=" + imgUrl + "&amp;title=Product+Title+as+it+will+be+seen+inside+Houzz&amp;ref=http%3A%2F%2Flivinginspace.staging.wpengine.com%2F");
```

Altogether that is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var currLi = $('li').filter(function() {
return $(this).css('z-index') == 20;
});

var imgUrl = $(currLi + '>div.slotholder>img').attr('src');

$('a.sb_network_button.houzz').attr("href", "http://www.houzz.com/imageClipperUpload?link=http%3A%2F%2Flivinginspace.staging.wpengine.com%2F&amp;source=button&amp;hzid=4036&amp;imageUrl=" + imgUrl + "&amp;title=Product+Title+as+it+will+be+seen+inside+Houzz&amp;ref=http%3A%2F%2Flivinginspace.staging.wpengine.com%2F");
});
```

I am pretty new to jquery, and I can't remember all the things I've tried but I have done everything I can and it still doesn't work. Also, I have noticed that when I put the code at the very end of the footer, it doesn't work at all (tried putting alerts, just to test), but when it's in the header or beginning of footer (before all other scripts) the alerts work, but I believe the problem might be that the actual li elements that I am trying to target are not yet created. Please help me with it, I've spent so many hours trying to figure this out.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To get the "li" with z-index of 20 you can do this, which will get the image URL inside of that "li":

```
var imgUrl;
$('li').each(function() {
    if($(this).css('zIndex') == 20) {
        imgUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    }
});
```

-------------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------------

I have made a JSFiddle that successfully gets an image src and then places it has the href on an a tag. See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vbWbP/)

The code is below (including the code above that I already had for finding the imgURL of the image with z-index of 20). Obviously, I am using two buttons in my example, but just for testing that the href is undefined initially, to set the href, then check it again.

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    //Get image with z-index = 20
    $('li').each(function() {
        if($(this).css('zIndex') == 20) {
            imgUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        }
    });
    $('.a').attr('href', imgUrl);
});

$('#btn2').click(function() {
    alert($('.a').attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: sry, my bad, by button I meant <a> element. Will give it a go and let you know if it works.

Comment: In that case, what you have for href should work on the anchor element. I would try switching how you check for z-index of 20 and see if that helps.

Comment: It seems like it's actually the problem with the que. Tried putting alert(imgUrl); and it returns undefined, so I assume that when I put the code in the head, those elements are not created yet. But for some reason, when I put the code at the very bottom, it's not working at all (even alert). Anyway, thanks for you answer, it's a much neater version of what I tried to do before.

Comment: If you post your HTML that might be helpful as to finding a solution, if you are indeed trying to call these functions before the elements are created.

Comment: that's a whole page html, let me know if you need only a portion of it. The page url is http://livinginspace.staging.wpengine.com/ and it's the revolution slider plugin that includes those elements I am trying to target

Comment: I found a way to get this to work messing around in a JSFiddle, which I have put in my answer. It's hard for me to find a way around it in your code just because I'm so unfamiliar with it. Hopefully you can use this to get it working.